# Create Access Database in Visual C++

Tags: ms-access, visual-c++, odbc, ado, dao

Currently I need to find a method to create an Access database in Visual C++ 2008, so that:

1. I can create the Access database in different formats, including Access 95/97 format, 2000 format, and 2007 accdb format.
2. I can create not only tables, but also other objects, including queries, reports, forms and macros in the Access database.
3. When adding a large volume of records into the tables, the method has a better performance.

I have searched online, and have found resourced such as [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1200421/How-to-use-ms-access-database-in-Cplusplus) which lists some methods, however, as far as I know, DAO seems to be deprecated.

How about the other methods?

Thanks

Comment: DAO is __NOT__ deprecated, only specific parts of it (ODBCDirect workspaces to connect to non-Access databases) are. It's broadly spread misinformation. If you want to create and manipulate more than just tables in Access databases, you need to use DAO.

Comment: Do you mean use Direct DAO to access Access? In this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/cc811599(v=office.12) , it said MFC DAO supports Jet engine up to 3.6 only.

Comment: @SimonMourier, It seems that is possible to create form, query, etc. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/aa11aea3-3f59-47c6-990a-1d8111989a0a/create-form-in-access-programatically?forum=accessdev

Comment: Yes but you need to have Access installed where you will run the code. Is this the case?

Comment: @alancc Indeed, I mean direct DAO/acedao.dll (which is COM-based and the documentation is mainly VBA-oriented, but you should be able to translate the concepts to C++ easily). Note that it requires either Access or the Access Database Engine to be installed on the computer.

Comment: You should use Access Runtime maybe, and call corresponding methods via it's API

Comment: If you want, you can also study binary format - https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000462.shtml

Comment: @VanNg, It seems that Access Runtime is larger, about 200 - 300 MB.

Comment: @VanNg That's for mdb files. There's no comprehensive resource on accdb files, which this question is about.

Comment: I don't agree. DAO library works in Access 2007 and upper also.

Comment: For suggested solution, if one calls: `Call CreateDatabaseFile("c:\test\a test database file.accdb")`, then the newer version of db would appear

Comment: @VanNg I'm referring to your binary format link, that's mdb only.

Comment: https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000463.shtml - accdb description, but yep, :No specification is publicly available." Anyway, I don't find reasons to work _only_ through binaries... this solution's cost seems to be too expensive

Answer (score 1):

As I have understood, you want to create database, objects in it, via calling some function and procedures. Best approach to my mind is to use DAO Library. Here is VBScript example:

```
Sub CreateDatabaseFile(ByVal strDbPath) 
    Dim wspDefault 'As Workspace
    Dim dbs      ' As Database
    Dim dbEngine ' DAO DB Engine    
    Dim dbLangGeneral
    dbLangGeneral = ";LANGID=0x0409;CP=1252;COUNTRY=0"
    Set dbEngine = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")
    Set wspDefault = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
    Set dbs = wspDefault.CreateDatabase(strDbPath, dbLangGeneral)
    Dim s
    s="CREATE TABLE tblCustomers (CustomerID INTEGER CONSTRAINT PK_tblCustomers PRIMARY KEY, " _
    & " [Last Name] TEXT(50) NOT NULL, [First Name] TEXT(50) NOT NULL, Phone TEXT(10), Email TEXT(50), " _
    & " Address TEXT(40)) "
    dbs.execute s
    dbs.Close

    Dim AccessApp
    Set AccessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    AccessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase strDbPath
    Dim frm 'As Form
    Dim ctlLabel 'As Control
    Dim  ctlText 'As Control
    Dim intDataX 'As Integer, intDataY As Integer
    Dim intDataY
    Dim intLabelX 'As Integer, intLabelY As Integer
    Dim intLabelY

    ' Create new form with tblCustomers table as its record source.
    Set frm = AccessApp.CreateForm
    'frm.Name = "MyForm"
    frm.RecordSource = "tblCustomers"

    ' Set positioning values for new controls.
    intLabelX = 100
    intLabelY = 100
    intDataX = 1000
    intDataY = 100

    ' Create unbound default-size text box in detail section.
    Dim acTextBox
    acTextBox = 109
    Set ctlText = AccessApp.CreateControl(frm.Name, acTextBox, , "", "", _
        intDataX, intDataY)
    ctlText.ControlSource = "Last Name"
    Dim acLabel
    acLabel = 100
    ' Create child label control for text box.
    Set ctlLabel = AccessApp.CreateControl(frm.Name, acLabel, , _
         ctlText.Name, "NewLabel", intLabelX, intLabelY)
    Dim acButton

    AccessApp.DoCmd.Save, frm.Name
    ' Restore form.
    AccessApp.DoCmd.Restore
    AccessApp.DoCmd.Quit
End Sub
Call CreateDatabaseFile("c:\test\a test database file.mdb")
```

Comment: And DAO is not deprecated totally, it updates its version number, during updating MS Access

Comment: Sorry but it seems impossible to create form, report, modules, macros via DAO. The only way is to use Access automation to do that?

Comment: It is possible to create tables, forms, elements on it, whatever you want via DAO. See methods of `Access.Application` object.

Comment: Thanks. That's Access automation.